# Why is Beautiful Soup's soup.find() bringing me empty content?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm currently working on web scraping with Python Beautiful Soup.

`<td id="cctv_camera_cnt" class="data">58</td>`

The '58' is the information that I'm trying to get

```
PATH=r'chromedriver.exe'
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("http://www.k-apt.go.kr/kaptinfo/openkaptinfo.do?menu_type=07")
selecting_apt=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="1"]/td[2]').click()
time.sleep(2) 
managing_facilities=driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-4").click()

current_page=driver.current_url
requests_page=requests.get(current_page)
soup=bs(requests_page.content,"lxml")
cc=soup.find('td', {"id":"cctv_camera_cnt"})
cc
```

The output shows

```
<td class="data" id="cctv_camera_cnt"></td>
```

The '58' is missing. It brought me with no content

```
cc.get_text()
```

brings me ''

`cc.contents`

brings me []

I tried both 'lxml' and 'html.parser', but they show the same results.

Your advice will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You've found the tag, which is correctly identified. Now get the string inside the tag: `cc.string`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice...!!!! It feels like I have a long way to go till I become used to web scraping

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two independent things. In this case, BeautifulSoup has nothing to do with Selenium because you are just getting the current_url of the page(which you already have) instead of the page source and then passing the URL to requests. So, what is the use of Selenium here? I hope you get my point. You should pass the HTML content to beautifulSoup instead of URL. So, you won't need requests library. Follow this:

```
html=driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
cc=soup.find('td', {"id":"cctv_camera_cnt"})
```

This will give you your desired output.

Comment: Oh it's now working!!!!!! I never thought I did something wrong when I was parsing the page. Thanks a lot you saved my day!!!